# How to search for following-sibling and their decendents?

Tags: xpath

This will give all the siblings following the current node.

```
./following-sibling::*[somecondition]
```

This is will give all the descendants of those siblings.

```
./following-sibling::*//*[somecondition]
```

Is there a way to combine the two better than the following?

```
./following-sibling::*[somecondition] | ./following-sibling::*//*[somecondition]
```

[xpath using // and descendant-or-self and self](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40708133/xpath-using-and-descendant-or-self-and-self)

The above page has nothing to do with my question. I am not asking self and its descendants.

Comment: Have you tried with `./following::*[somecondition]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [xpath using // and descendant-or-self and self](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40708133/xpath-using-and-descendant-or-self-and-self)

Comment: @PaulProgrammer  That page does not answer my question.

Answer (score -1):

you should be good to use `following::*` instead of `following-sibling::*`. Below is the example.

[image]

`following::*` checked both the siblings and the children under siblings.

Comment: I don't think it is correct. I will get everything including ancestors that are above the current level.  https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp `Selects everything in the document after the closing tag of the current node`

Comment: following will get all the nodes but you have to filter them using the condition.